# How does batch work when iterating through a list performance wise?

Tags: spring, performance, hibernate, persistence

So basically, i have a method which is called UpdateAll, the List sas contains both already persisted datas and to be merged datas.
I have a similar method, called addAll, which iterate through a list that only contains to be persisted data.

The method "AddAll" takes around 3 seconds for around 3k datas no matter what.
The method "updateAll" takes around 3 seconds for around 3k datas which an empty table, but if the table hold around 50k rows, it start affecting performance.

Is there a way to improve this method for it to not be affected ?

```
    @Transactional
    public List<Sa> updateAll(List<Sa> sas, Long scenaId, String username)
            throws Exception {

        for (Sa sa : sas) {
            if (sa.getGenericMetrics() != null) {
                sa.setGenericMetrics(
                        DimensionUtils.computeGenericMetrics(sa.getGenericMetrics()));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sas.size(); i = i + BATCH_SIZE) {
            if (i + BATCH_SIZE > sas.size()) {
                List<Sa> tmpSas = sas.subList(i, sas.size());
                saRepository.saveAll(tmpSas);
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.clear();
                break;
            }

            List<Sa> tmpSas = sas.subList(i, i + BATCH_SIZE);
            saRepository.saveAll(tmpSas);
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
        }

        return sas;

    }
```

Comment: If there are indexes on the table or other constraints inserting might take more and more time.